# Delete method returning error after devise logout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm running into a problem that I'm not exactly sure how to fix.

I have a simple to do list application with AJAX functionality on methods such as 'new', 'create', 'complete', 'delete', as well as Devise authentication.

When I first enter a new session with a User, all of these methods work without a problem. Additionally, the tasks are saved to only the user account, which is perfect.

However, when I log out of an account, and then log back in, the delete method no longer works. I receive the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Task with 'id'=)
```

My tasks_controller.rb is below:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @task = current_user.tasks.all
  end
  def new
    @task = Task.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
    end
  end
  def create
    @task = current_user.tasks.new(task_params)
    @task.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
  def update
    @task = current_user.tasks.find(params[:id])
    @task.toggle :complete
    @task.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
  def destroy
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @task.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
    end
  end
  private
  def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:id, :title, :complete)
  end
end
```

I'm not exactly sure how to fix this problem. Would anyone have an idea on what is going wrong here?

EDIT:

I noticed that on my index page, I have a link to destroy the user's session at the top:

```
<%= link_to "Log Out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

I'm wondering if rails is having some trouble with this as both the logout link and the delete link are referencing the same method. If so, how can I change the name of the delete method for Task?

```
<div class="delete"><%= link_to "X", task_path(@task), method: :delete, remote: true %></div>
```

Comment: Put byebug in view and check the value of @task. I think it is not integer type.

Comment: Where do you define `@task`?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh what do you mean? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: I mean, where are you initialising it? or setting its value? I don't see that code above.

Answer (score 0):

What is `@task` referencing? It looks to me like you've set `@task` to a collection `@task = current_user.tasks.all`.
Which would be why your delete method can't find a specific record to delete.

-EDIT-

Change `@task` in your index controller to `@tasks` as it is a collection.
In your view, do something like:

```
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
 <div><%= task.title %><div class="delete"><%= link_to "X", task_path(task), method: :delete, remote: true %></div></div>
<% end %>
```

The key here is that you have `task_path(task)` which is referencing a specific task id as opposed to `task_path(@task)` which is referencing a collection of tasks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I wanted the application to only display tasks created by the current_user, would the current_user helper not work in the index method?

Comment: You've set @task to a collection in your index method. I'm guessing in your view you have something like this:

Comment: I figured out the problem. I was referencing "@task" in my path for the link when I should have been using "f.id" as I had a each do |f| statement prior to this. 

Thank you for your help on this.